# Python threading-- Getting a traceback that does not tell what has happened

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I am trying to build a chat app with python sockets. I want that my program always recieives message therefore, I used threading but I am getting a traceback that does not tell what has happened. Simply,

```
PS C:\Users\rauna> python "c:/Users/rauna/Documents/New folder/meg.py"
S or Cc
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.496.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
```

on client side and

```
C:\Users\rauna\Documents\New folder>C:/Users/rauna/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python.exe "c:/Users/rauna/Documents/New folder/meg.py"    
S or Cs
Connection from: ('192.168.43.114', 50802)
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.496.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
```

on server side. [Here](https://gist.github.com/raunky/5ad1735cfa55368d7d88e3634697afe4), is the complete code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture the exception within the thread itself, and "transfer" the exception to the main thread.

Wrap your thread code in `try...except`, grab the exception, and stuff it inside a variable that the main thread can see. The main thread should be looping + idling, and when the main thread sees that variable contains an exception, reraise the exception.